# How can I execute another program with Electron JS

Tags: node.js, electron

I want to execute another program while running electron app. How can I do this?

My Code

```
var child = require('child_process').execFile;
var executablePath = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chromedriver.exe";

child(executablePath, function(err, data) {
    if(err){
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

Comment: And your code doesn't work? What happened? Anyways, I believe you should use exec or spawn not execFile.

Comment: Hi, my code does not work and does not print anything on the screen.